# Store images in browser cache - optimal way to load images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I'm currently loading multiple images for different breakpoints (desktop, tablet, mobile) and `ng-repeating` through them, then hiding the images that shouldn't currently be shown:

```
<img ng-repeat="img in module.imgs" src="{{img.src}}" class="image-{{img.type}}" style="top: {{img.pos}}px">
```

This `ng-repeat` causes all three image elements to be loaded as elements when only one is shown at a time.

```
desktop.png GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   4 ms    
tablet.png  GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   5 ms    
mobile.png  GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   3 ms
```

To improve this, I tried loading only the image that meets the current breakpoint:

```
<img src="{{image.src}}" class="image-{{image.type}}" style="top: {{image.pos}}px">

    $scope.$watch($scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
        $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
        $scope.image = null;

        if ($scope.windowWidth >= breakPoints['desk']) {
            $scope.image =  $scope.module.imgs[0];
        } else if ($scope.windowWidth >= breakPoints['mid']) {
            $scope.image =  $scope.module.imgs[1];
        } else {
            $scope.image =  $scope.module.imgs[2];
        }

    }, true);
```

Unfortunately, each time I hit a breakpoint, it requests the image even if they've been loaded:

```
desktop.png GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   4 ms    
tablet.png  GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   5 ms    
mobile.png  GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   3 ms    
tablet.png  GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   4 ms    
mobile.png  GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   5 ms
```

How can I cache or otherwise store these images such that they're loaded as needed once?

Controller datastructure:

```
$scope.module = {
            imgs: [
                {
                    type: 'desktop',
                    src: 'img/desktop.png',
                    pos: 0
                },
                {
                    type: 'tablet',
                    src: 'img/tablet.png',
                    pos: 0
                },
                {
                    type: 'mobile',
                    src: 'img/mobile.png',
                    pos: 0
                }
            ]
        };
```

Comment: In `desktop.png GET 304 png angular.js:3151 243 B   4 ms`, is 304 the HTTP status code? Do you really need to redirect those requests?

Comment: @ThomasLandauer The `304` HTTP status code is not a redirect.

Comment: @Sohnee: Thanks, just noticed that myself ;-) `304` is `Not Modified`.

Comment: Try using `css` to set `background-image` , which should request image at most once

Answer (score 0):

The `304` status code means you have told the browser that the image hasn't been modified, so it doesn't need to re-download it.

You could improve this further by sending caching headers with the image, which would stop the browser even making an HTTP request for the image once it has it cached.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to setup a caching directive on your server, like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg|json)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

In this case, the caching duration is very long, so keep this in mind when your image changes. Basically this is the most efficient way to cache an image, but you need to change the image name when its contents change. Or you set the value lower (its in seconds).

Now, the browser should't even ask for a newer version for the cached image, obliterating the "304" request.